# Routing algorithm for drawing non-intersecting lines

Tags: javascript, algorithm, routes

I'm working on a flowchart system in JS, that allows the user to click on one element followed by another, and the program inserts an arrow connecting them. For this, I need a line-drawing algorithm which meets the following criteria:

- Only straight lines/90deg turns
- Guaranteed to take an efficient route, such that...
- ... it can take into consideration other lines (as it cannot intersect) - e.g, if I insert one line, and then another, it is able to draw the second without having to rearrange the first, or take a wildly inefficient route to get to its destination to avoid the first line.

If you know any algorithms which fit the bill (I've only found ones that match just one or at most two of the criteria), I'd be interested; also, if there's a JS implementation I can steal then please link that too.

Some notes:

- Time complexity does not matter, as long as the result is aesthetically pleasant
- There can be multiple lines originating from or entering one element. This is to allow for loopbacks/subroutines.
- Lines can go on top of each other, just not perpendicularly across one another.

Examples:

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUvOH.png)

I click on one element...

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3YID.png)

... and then on another, which then inserts the arrow between them.

[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gm1ZR.png)

If I continue this, I expect to get a linear sequence, with the arrows inserted automagically.

[image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qj3cl.png)

Alternatively, I can make use of multiple inputs/outputs to get a more closed chart, generating a more complex result.

[image 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJkmw.png)

I should be able to do this in any order to get the same result.

Comment: This seems like a 'finding the minimum [`spanning tree`](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Spanning_tree)' problem. An implementation of an algorithm for it can be found here: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/blob/40a1a8f1e9e9e086ff8f4e43fb122194a2252b1f/src/collection/algorithms/kruskal.js

Comment: @MarcusViníciusMonteiro not really, the user draws the lines. You could look at existing products which offer similar functionality such as draw.io

Comment: @MarcusViníciusMonteiro Thanks for your suggestion! I've looked through the Wikipedia article, however, and I'm not sure if it's what I need: my project entails _multiple_ lines (and their relationship), rather than just joining all elements together.

Comment: @MarcusViníciusMonteiro The problem is to allocate lines of a flowchart, not a MST.  We don't get to add/remove connections.

Comment: A picture would help.

Comment: The third bullet item is self-contradictory, which is why you won't find an existing implementation.

Comment: BTW, the problem you describe is a (somewhat) simplified version of the [printed-circuit-board routing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_(electronic_design_automation)). State of the art programs that solve that problem cost 1000's of US dollars, and take hours to run. And that's if they are allowed to move all of the lines around, and are allowed to use multiple layers (i.e. lines can intersect). From the linked article: *"Almost every problem associated with routing is known to be intractable."*

Comment: @user3386109 I've checked that Wikipedia article already, but in my brief research I couldn't find anything suitable.

Comment: @Yola done; added multiple to help elaborate. If someone could edit it with embeds, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @user3386109, regarding your first comment, I've added another note which should help elaborate. I just want the _most neat_ chart, not necessarily a neat one (if it is so complicated)